# Data is not loading exactly from database with Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `studenthistory` table (studentid, modified time, fname, lname) which has 8 records now in it. `Studenthistory` will be updated with new rows regularly when student `fname` or `lname` are modified.

So, I need to display the history of data, but the updated data is not coming exactly as in the table. Total number of records are coming but it's modified time and `fname` and `lname` is not coming correctly. The first record only duplicated to all remaining 7 records. What is the reason for this. I'm using this query to get the data.

```
 var studentData = from p in context.Studenthistory
                   where p.id == 112
                   orderby p.Last_Modified descending
                   select p
```

Comment: What's the **primary key** on your `Studenthistory` table?

Comment: We are not maintaining any primary key for this table. But, last_modified and id combination will give the unique results or data.

Comment: The problem is: if your table doesn't have a primary key, EF will take all non-nullable columns and regards those as "makeshift PK". Now if your rows all have the same values in those non-nullable columns, EF will read the first row, and any subsequent row will be seen as a "duplicate" of that already existing row and thus the remaining data isn't really read - EF just "duplicates" the already stored values.....

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for the quick answer. I have the similar situation now in the table. How can I over come this, do I need to have any primary key for this table? or any other alternate solution

Comment: The simplest and most sustainable solution would be to have a proper primary key on the table - EF will pick that up and handle it properly